# Finding patterns within array

Tags: bash

I have an array of elements and I would like to find all elements that have the following form:

```
$i or ${i}
```

Where i can be any natural number?
Can this be achieved without using AWK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `grep` if you prefer. For instance:

```
a=('$1' '$3' '$(4)' '5' 'a' '$a' '$1' '${52}')
for i in ${a[*]}; do
    if [ $(echo "$i" | grep -E "^[$][0-9]+$") ]; then     # First possible pattern
        echo "$i"
    elif [ $(echo "$i" | grep -E "^[$]{[0-9]+}$") ]; then # Second possible pattern
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
$1
$3
$1
${52}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
ARRAY=('a' '1' '$1' '${1}')
FOUND=()
for __ in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    [[ $__ =~ ^[$]([0-9]+|[{][0-9]+[}])$ ]] && FOUND+=("$__")
done
echo "Found: ${FOUND[*]}"
```

Output:

```
Found: $1 ${1}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using an obfuscated variable name? Will probably confuse a lot of newbies.

Comment: @jaypal Besies `__`, my favorite variable for iteration is `A` but before I had named the array as `A` so I decided to use `__`, then didn't bother to change it back to `A` when I finished. I don't think it's that difficult to comprehend as `__` is explicitly declared in the for loop.

Comment: True, for someone aware of `for loop` usage can comprehend that easily, but others might just think `__` is a special variable to be used in `for loop` or a variable that gets values from array, similar to `$_` variable in `perl`. You answer is clearly better than the accepted one so just wanted to offer my 2 cents. Nothing personal. `:)`